# How to solve R of Problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics

what's the meaning of this?

R o R o R o R = R o R o R

As I understand it means R of R of R of R is same as R of R of R
But It seems there something more in discrete mathematics

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math problem, not a programming one.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider a relation R={(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)} defined on set S={1,2,3}.

R o R  is calculated as follows

```
     R o R(1) = R(2) = 3
     R o R(2) = R(3) = 1
     R o R(3) = R(1) = 2
```

R o R = {(1,3),(2,1),(3,2)}

similarly R o R o R = {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)}

R o R o R o R = {(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)}

for this example R o R o R o R = R

In case your question R o R o R o R = R o R o R, The relation R={(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)} satisfies the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct; the meaning of:

```
R o R o R o R = R o R o R
```

Is this:

> R of R of R of R is equal to R of R of R

We can infer some more about the nature of R based on this equality by composing with R's inverse:

```
R o R o R o R = R o R o R
(R^-1 o R^-1 o R^-1) o (R o R o R o R) = (R^-1 o R^-1 o R^-1) o (R o R o R)
(R^-1 o R^-1) o (R^-1 o R) o (R o R o R) = (R^-1 o R^-1) o (R^-1 o R) o (R o R)
(R^-1 o R^-1) o I o (R o R o R) = (R^-1 o R^-1) o I o (R o R)
(R^-1 o R^-1) o (R o R o R) = (R^-1 o R^-1) o (R o R)
```

You can repeat this process and find that:

```
R = I
```

is the only admissible solution.